# Iterating over groups within a grouped df in python and returning a value based on an aggregation

Tags: python

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
    sample_id  conc      effect
0        1000     1          50
1        1000    10          70
2        1000   100          80
3        1000  1000         100
4        1001     1          20
5        1001    10          40
6        1001   100          50
7        1001  1000          60
8        1002     1          20
9        1002    10          30
10       1002   100          40
11       1002  1000          50
12       1003     1          60
13       1003    10          80
14       1003   100          90
15       1003  1000         100
16       1004     1          10
17       1004    10          20
18       1004   100          30
19       1004  1000          40
```

What I want to do is iterate over the sample_id groups to determine the lowest conc that causes an effect 80 or above. And if it doesn't reach that threshold, it would give the max concentration used. I want to append this to a list as a dictionary. For the above example, the result I'm looking for would be:

```
results = 
[{sample : 1000, lec : 100}, 
{sample : 1001, lec : 1000}, 
{sample: 1002, lec : 1000}, 
{sample : 1003, lec : 10}, 
{sample : 1004, lec: 1000}]
```

I've tried `df.groupby('sample_id')` but haven't figured out how to iterate over the groups to return the proper conc. I also was trying o iterate using something like `for sample in df['sample_id'].unique()` but wasn't sure where to go from there. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Even if you do not how to reach your target by using Pandas, it is good, at least provide a code to get the solition by non-pandad way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`pd.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) you can find the [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html) of rows with `effect >= 80` for each group. Empty filtered groups will result in `nan`. Then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) those with the [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html) of `conc` for every group.

Converting to a `dataframe` to use [`to_dict('records')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).

```py
s = df.groupby('sample_id')
(s.apply(lambda x: x[x.effect >= 80].conc.min()).fillna(s.conc.max())
    .astype('int')
    .to_frame()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0:'lec','sample_id':'sample'})
    .to_dict('records'))
```

Out:

```
[{'lec': 100, 'sample': 1000},
 {'lec': 1000, 'sample': 1001},
 {'lec': 1000, 'sample': 1002},
 {'lec': 10, 'sample': 1003},
 {'lec': 1000, 'sample': 1004}]
```